# Detecting types of Drifts in data

Tags: machine-learning-model, data-drift

Given I have two data files, is it possible to detect between the covariate, concept and label drift? That has occurred between them?

There are various methods to detect concept drift. But is it possible to differentiate between the covariate, concept and label drift.